# What is the best way to use DataTables with Meteor JS

Tags: meteor, datatables

I've been trying to use DataTables.net, a jquery extension, in my Meteor project.

Specifically when I add DataTables ("meteor npm install --save datatables.net”) to my project I get a console error  "bootstrap.js:15Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3”  which based on what I read says I have jquery twice??? How do I make sure i have one?   Then even if I actually try adding datatable, such as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#regulations-table').DataTable();
} );
```

then I get another console error "jquery.dataTables.js:5854 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined"

So again, What's the best way to deploy datatables with Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you display comes from your MongoDB, a **very** popular package (with Blaze) is [`aldeed:tabular`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular).

There are forks and equivalent packages for React as well.

It takes care for you of the subscriptions, pagination and server-side search / filtering.

Comment: When I look at aldeed:tabular...the last issue posted is "Is this repository dead or still alive?"  It looks like the library hasn't been touched in 7 months...so using a library that isn't maintained doesn't seem like a best practice.

Comment: Yep that is the drawback of Open Source unfortunately. In the case of this package, the author is very busy and did not handover. But you can look for forks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Blaze, it would be simple for you to install a package https://atmospherejs.com/ephemer/reactive-datatables

This basically wraps the jquery plugin and makes it easy to integrate.